# Missing Set-Cookie Header When Using express-session

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, express-session, setcookie

Recently, I moved a service to a new server. While everything was working fine on the old server, I wasn't able to log in on the new server. After some investigation, I found out that the response from the login endpoint was missing the Set-Cookie header, even when the username and password were correct.

Here are some key code snippets:

```typescript
import * as expressSession from 'express-session';

app.use(
  expressSession({
    secret: process.env.SES_SCRET,
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: sessionAge,
      sameSite: 'none',
      secure: true
    },
    store: sessionStore,
    name: 'LID',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
  })
);
```

nginx reverse proxy configuration:

```nginx
#PROXY-START/

location ^~ /
{
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header REMOTE-HOST $remote_addr;

  #Persistent connection related configuration

  add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

  #Set Nginx Cache
  
  set $static_fileWeFecuJG 0;
  if ( $uri ~* "\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js|woff|woff2)$" )
  {
    set $static_fileWeFecuJG 1;
    expires 12h;
  }
  if ( $static_fileWeFecuJG = 0 )
  {
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
  }
}
#PROXY-END/
```

This was a rather strange problem that took me a long time to solve. But eventually, I did figure it out. So, I wanted to share my experience in case it could help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the reason for this problem was quite simple. It was because in the `express-session` configuration, `cookie.secure` was set to `true`, but the nginx reverse proxy was not telling the application that even though it was using HTTPS, it was still running in HTTP mode.

To fix this, all you need is to add `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;` to your nginx reverse proxy configuration.

Therefore, the correct nginx reverse proxy configuration should look like this:

```nginx
#PROXY-START/

location ^~ /
{
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header REMOTE-HOST $remote_addr;
  
  #THIS IS IMPORTANT FOR COOKIE SECURE MODE
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

  #Persistent connection related configuration

  add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

  #Set Nginx Cache
  
  set $static_fileWeFecuJG 0;
  if ( $uri ~* "\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js|woff|woff2)$" )
  {
    set $static_fileWeFecuJG 1;
    expires 12h;
  }
  if ( $static_fileWeFecuJG = 0 )
  {
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
  }
}
#PROXY-END/
```

Comment: I am currently having the same issue, but it only happens when using Safari, i have set `x-forwarded-proto` header. it works fine in chrome and firefox, any idea?